# Check compatibility with Linux before installing

Tags: drivers, system-installation, settings, hardware-compatibility, reference

I have a new computer, more precisely an *Asus N750J*, and I would like to check the compatibility of the hardware with Linux before installing (dual boot is the plan), to be prepared and prevent problems and disappointments. I have already seen that I'll probably need to install *Bumblebee*, but I don't have a specific checklist so that I can be sure I'm ready to go for the installation. I'd like to do this as fast and painlessly as possible.

The plan is to install *Debian*, I don't have a strong preference on *Debian Stable* or *Testing* (probably *testing* will be a better option).

The details in italics are specific for my case, but I think this is probably a fairly general question. Detailing the answer may be unfeasible for a site of short answers as SE, if so, please provide references or pointers to general guidelines.

If there are details missing or the question has to be modified to suit better the format please tell me and I'll change whatever needs to be changed.

Comment: One usually wants to check compatibility before purchasing. If you have already bought it, the simplest thing is just to try an install and see what happens. Deal with problems as you run into them. The Debian installers, like other Linux distribution installers, has got a lot smarter over the years, and will probably handle most things you can throw at it.

Comment: not to mention they all offer LiveCDs so you do not have to install anything to see what hardware is detected.

Comment: @rob: good point.

Comment: Thank you both. I have a new computer but I have not purchased a new computer (BTW: nothing illegal going on here). I'll try to find the live CD for Debian and make a USB drive bootable, hopefully my computer will not explode (does someone remember the LG CD/DVD drives or was it a urban legend?) I still think the question can be useful for many people.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running a Live Media (either a CD/DVD or USB stick) of the distribution you want to install. This will give you the best idea of how well it works on your computer.

There are online databases that list hardware that is supported by Linux. This one for example:
http://en.opensuse.org/Hardware

The problem with these is that there isn't really one central database and I don't know of any one of these sites that is fully complete on it's own.

I recommend that you read [this article on Linux.com](http://www.linux.com/news/hardware/drivers/8203-is-my-hardware-linux-compatible-find-out-here).